# Vertical line in footer and header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to make my footer and header look like [this beautiful apple manual](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1569/en_US/ipad_2_user_guide.pdf).

I think, I should use the `fancyhdr` package. But, I need an example to see how I should use it in this case (for vertical lines). I have found a lot about horizontal line, but not vertical ones.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is the [`clean-thesis`](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) template what you're looking for? (It's purpose is to emulate this layout. It goes way beyond the footer only. But you can fiddle with the code to emulate the footer only.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[RO]{\vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage\hskip\linepagesep\vfootline}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \newskip\linepagesep \linepagesep 5pt\relax
  \def\vfootline{%
    \begingroup\color{blue}\rule[-990pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

For the head its very similar. Here, I used the `picture` environment to ensure the right positioning:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){\vheadline\hskip\linepagesep\thechapter}\end{picture}}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){\thechapter\hskip\linepagesep\vheadline}\end{picture}}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \newskip\linepagesep \linepagesep 5pt\relax
  \def\vheadline{%
    \begingroup\color{blue}\rule[-5pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe you could help how to make same thing with header? I mean my title of chapter should have a vertical line with chapter number.

Comment: @Satnam -- added the part for headers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`clean-thesis`](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) template, that aims to emulate the style of Apple's documents.

Therefor, you need to download the archive on its [developer website](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/). You unzip the files and will find three main documents:

- `thesis-example.pdf` and `thesis-example.tex`: A document using the clean-thesis and the root of its source-code: so that you can compare the result with its LaTeX source (a lot to learn this way!);
- `cleanthesis.sty` : the package definition itself. If you want to use it in other documents, you need to install is in the right folder of your tex distro, or to copy it in the same folder than the `*.tex` file you're using.

*Nota: this package adapts the outlook of `KOMA-script` classes. You'll need some changes if you use other classes. It also redefines *a lot* of parameters. If you prefer, you can just fiddle in the code of `cleanthesis.sty` and copy-past the features you like. Its a bit of work, sure, but you will learn a lot!