# Vertical line in footer problem with chapter (fancyhdr)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

This is practically a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303647/vertical-line-in-footer-and-header).

The solution there works great for an article, but does not work with chapters, i.e. with report or book classes. As you can see here on the first page of a chapter there is just a number in the middle without a vrule:

[image]

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[RO]{\vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage\hskip\linepagesep\vfootline}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \newskip\linepagesep \linepagesep 5pt\relax
  \def\vfootline{%
    \begingroup\color{blue}\rule[-990pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test 1}
\lipsum
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum
\chapter{Test 2}
\lipsum
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As always: thanks so much for any advice in advance :-)

Comment: What is the question? I see the vertical footline -- if this is not wanted, remove the `\vfootline` related code

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear from the picture, but on the first page of a chapter there is just a number in the middle without a vrule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chapter pages use page style `plain`. So you have to redefine this style too. Use:

```
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage\hskip\linepagesep\vfootline}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  }
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[RO]{\vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage\hskip\linepagesep\vfootline}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage\hskip\linepagesep\vfootline}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  }
  \newskip\linepagesep \linepagesep 5pt\relax
  \def\vfootline{%
    \begingroup\color{blue}\rule[-990pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test 1}
\lipsum
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Test 2}
\lipsum
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, they do! Now I feel dumb, but thanks so much! :-)